# Play an audio sequence in react render

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to get two audio files to play one after another. 
In my render function I have

getnext is basically not working. I've tried returning JSX that creates an audio object and then autoplays but that does that work. I've tried changing the src of my existing audio object and then playing but that doesnt work.

Suggestions on how to play two audio files in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if you're using any library, but you can do this using pure `React.JS`

Just make sure you're leveraging the native `onEnded()` event-listener that all `audio`tags have. Hopefully you like KPOP: https://codesandbox.io/s/audio-playlist-42ou0

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import bigbang from "./bigbang.mp3";
import girlsgeneration from "./girlsgeneration.mp3";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentFileIndex: 0,
      audioFiles: [
        { name: "girlsgeneration", source: girlsgeneration },
        { name: "bigbang", source: bigbang }
      ]
    };
  }

  goToNextSong = () => {
    const { currentFileIndex, audioFiles } = this.state;

    if (currentFileIndex < audioFiles.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        currentFileIndex: currentFileIndex + 1
      });
      //restart playlist
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currentFileIndex: 0
      });
    }
  };

  createAudioPlayer = () => {
    const { currentFileIndex, audioFiles } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Current Song: {audioFiles[currentFileIndex].name}</h4>
        <audio
          src={audioFiles[currentFileIndex].source}
          onEnded={this.goToNextSong}
          controls
          autoPlay
        />
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createAudioPlayer()}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```